# Inter-process communication using MemoryMappedFiles or Named Pipes in VC++ and C# in Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-c++, ipc, named-pipes, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to communicate between a VC++ DLL and a C# application. I've read tons of resources and material, I tried to do it with both MemoryMapped files and Pipes, but unfortunately I couldn't get to work.

Here's how I create the "receiver"/server part written in C#:

```
// MemoryMappedFile approach
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(
            @"myMMF",
            1024*1024,
            MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute);

// Named Pipe approach
NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("myPipe", PipeDirection.InOut);
```

This is the VC++ counterpart:

```
// MMF approach
HANDLE fmap = ::OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, false, (LPCWSTR)"myMMF");
if(fmap == NULL)
    return errorMsg();

// Named pipe
HANDLE pipe = ::CreateFile((LPCWSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if(pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return errorMsg();
```

My problem is, that regardless of which approach I use, the open calls always return a "file not found" error. The applications both run under the same user account on my 64-bit Windows 7. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
::CreateFile((LPCWSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe", ...)
```

That cannot work, you cannot cast a char* to a wide string, a conversion is required.  But not necessary here since this is a string literal.  Make it a unicode literal by prefixing an L

```
::CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe", ...)
```

Same problem with the MMF.  Also consider that it doesn't make much sense to use an out-of-process communication mechanism to talk to a DLL.  Just load it in-process.  Use pinvoke or a C++/CLI wrapper.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem. The dll is loaded by another process, I think I don't have any other options.